# running a android test project from device

Tags: android, testing

I created a android robotium test project, and it runs successfully from eclipse on device and on emulator.

even that the test app apears in the manage apps, its icon doesn't appear on the home screen.
i need to send it to to a potential client (not a programmer), that will install it and run it straight from his phone, but how he will run it, if there is no icon to run it from?

i tried all kinds of selutions, but i need something for a not technical client.

here is the code of the main class:

```
package genericTest.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class Main extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private FunctonsForViews mFunctonsForViews;
    private Random mRand;
    private Solo mSolo;
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.OnOApps.NRG.MainActivity";

    private final int DELAY = 50; 
    private final int SCREEN_SIZE = 1280;
    private final int ERROR_COUNT_LIMIT = 10;
    private final int CLICK_ON_LOOP_LIMIT = 8;
    private final int WHAITING_FOR_VIEWS_LIMIT = 10;

    private static Class launcherActivityClass;
    private static int error_count = 0;

    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class
                    .forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Main() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
        mSolo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());

        Context context = getActivity();
        KeyguardManager km = 
                  (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if (km.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
        {
          KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = km.newKeyguardLock("some_tag");
          lock.disableKeyguard();
          SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        }
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
    }

    /*
     * runs the test for the app.
     */
    public void testMethod()
    {
        mFunctonsForViews = new FunctonsForViews(mSolo);
        mSolo.sleep(DELAY * DELAY);

        mRand = new Random();

        /*
         * the test will take place in the loop, and will be limit in time.
         * in every iteration it will get the vies in activity's, and run a test on a random view.
         */
        for(int i=0 ; ; i += DELAY)
        { 
            Log.i("starting eteration", "" + i);
            mSolo.unlockScreen();
            ArrayList Views = mSolo.getViews();
            int arraySize = Views.size();
            if (arraySize == 0)// now View in activity.
            {
                whenNoViewsInScreen(Views, arraySize);
            }
            if (arraySize != 0)
            {
                int ViewIndexInArray = mRand.nextInt(arraySize + 2);
                if (ViewIndexInArray == arraySize)
                {
                    mSolo.scrollDown();
                }

                else if (ViewIndexInArray == arraySize + 1)     
                {
                    if (!mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString().split(" ")[1].equals
                            (LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME))
                            {
                                goingBack();
                            }
                }
                else
                {
                    View randomView = (View)(Views.get(ViewIndexInArray));
                    runTestOnOneView(randomView);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * performing clicks onScreen()
     */
    public void myClickOnScreen()
    {
        try {
            mSolo.unlockScreen();
            mSolo.clickOnScreen(mRand.nextInt(SCREEN_SIZE), mRand.nextInt(SCREEN_SIZE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error_count++;
        } catch (Error e2) {
            error_count++;
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    /*
     * there is no Views available.
     * we will try pressing on screen or the goBack function.
     */
    public void whenNoViewsInScreen(ArrayList Views, int arraySize)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WHAITING_FOR_VIEWS_LIMIT; j++)
        {
            for (int k= 0; k < CLICK_ON_LOOP_LIMIT; k++)
            {   
                myClickOnScreen();
            }

            Views = mSolo.getViews();
            arraySize = Views.size();
            if (arraySize != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            mSolo.sleep(DELAY);
            Views = mSolo.getViews();
            arraySize = Views.size();
            if (arraySize != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        if (!mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString().split(" ")[1].equals
                (LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME))
                {
                    goingBack();
                }
        mSolo.sleep(DELAY);
        return;
    }

    public void runTestOnOneView(View randomView)
    {
        String rawViewName = randomView.getClass().getName();
        String viewName = parseRawViewName(rawViewName);
        if (viewName.contains("ActionBarContainer"))
        {
            return;
        }
        MyRunnable  myRunnable = mFunctonsForViews.getMethodMap().get(viewName);
        try{
            if (myRunnable != null)
            {
                myRunnable.run((View)randomView);               
            }
            else // view not in map.
            {
                boolean inMap = false;
                Iterator it = mFunctonsForViews.getMethodMap().entrySet().iterator();
                /*
                 * iterating in case the View is a version of one of View in map
                 * example:
                 * View is "CustomEditText", and map contains o view "EditText".
                 */
                while (it.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    if (   viewName.contains((String)pairs.getKey())   )
                    {
                        inMap = true;
                        // next two lines changed
                        myRunnable = (MyRunnable)(pairs.getValue());
                        myRunnable.run((View)randomView);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (inMap == false)
                {

                    if (viewName.contains("Layout"))
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    mSolo.clickOnView((View)randomView);
                }
                error_count = 0;
            }
        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            if(error_count > ERROR_COUNT_LIMIT &&
                    !(mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString().split(" ")[1].equals(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME)))    
            {
                goingBack();
                error_count = 0;
            }
            return;

        }catch(Error error)
        {

            error.printStackTrace();
            error_count ++;
            if(error_count > ERROR_COUNT_LIMIT &&
                    !(mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString().split(" ")[1].equals(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME)))    
            {
                goingBack();
                error_count = 0;
            }
            return;
        }   
        mSolo.sleep(DELAY);
    }

    /*
     * performs a goBack command surrounded with catch/try
     */
    public void goingBack()
    {
        try {
            String currentActivity = mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString();
            Log.e("in function before", "going back" );
            mSolo.goBack();
            if (mSolo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().toString().equals(currentActivity))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++)
                {
                    myClickOnScreen();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Error e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * extract the name of View from raw View name.
     * example:
     * raw View name: android.widget.TextView
     * raw View name:TextView
     */
    public String parseRawViewName(String rawViewName)
    {
        if (rawViewName.contains(" "))
        {
            String [] array = rawViewName.split(" ");
            rawViewName = array [0];
        }

        if (rawViewName.contains(".") || rawViewName.contains("$"))
        {
            String [] array = rawViewName.split("\\.|$");
            rawViewName = array [array.length-1];
        }
        return rawViewName;
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mSolo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to run the tests from "Icon on Home Screen". The tests are managed by the IDE with the InstrumentationRunner. So if you want to allow the client to run your tests on his device he also needs to checkout the project in Eclipse/Android Studio and run the tests.

Comment: Nearly correct, technically the test APK can be given to the client. Then the test can be run using an adb command from a PC connected to the phone. However, you are correct that there is no way to run the test from the device itself, without rooting the phone (AFAIK).